# How to know exactly which php code slow down site?

Tags: php

Site is on MODX EVO cms, i made google speed test - server response 2,5 sec.

I have tried to gzip css and js, so +10 to load speed, but server response 2,5 sec.

Site has integrated widgets like inline chat, may be i need to load scripts of it and other out site resources asynchronous?

In html code in bottom i see record that exactly PHP-scripts are loading 2,5 sec. It is possible to view exactly what PHP-script is so fat?

may be i can see it in ISP-manager?

Comment: This ? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501641/why-is-php-script-slowing-down

Comment: No, not pass for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need, is a [profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21133/simplest-way-to-profile-a-php-script). This is the only thing that will tell you what parts of the script is slow, and only once you know that can you figure out why.

I also recommend learning more about the [Big-O](https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/) notation, as that'll help you understand and explain the complexity of the code you're looking at.

Comment: good, but...hosting don't want to install  KCacheGrind...thank you

Comment: Profilers are generally run on the development environment, not production. Add it to your local web server, the one you do all of your testing on. If you don't have one, I strongly recommend installing it now: It will make things a whole lot easier for you in the long run.